# How do I paste text using the Mindterm Java SSH client on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server?

Tags: nano

I am using windows and is connecting to an ubuntu server I want to add this line to a text file

```
/dev/xvdf       /mnt1   auto    defaults,nobootwait     0       0
```

obviously I prefer to copy and paste that rather than typing it

So I do  nano /etc/fstab in amazon ec2

Then what?

I can't paste anything. How do I paste lines like that to nano or any other linux text editor?

Comment: *Which program* are you using to connect in Windows? Most will provide a paste functionality from your local clipboard.

Comment: The amazon ec2 has this thing called mindterm

Answer (score 2):

- [Mindterm](http://www.cryptzone.com/products/mindterm/) is a browser-based, Java-applet SSH client.
- Copy/paste may be available using either the *Edit* menu or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> (Copy) or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> (Paste) shortcuts:

  [image]
- Copy/paste from your local clipboard *may not* be available depending on the version of Java you have installed and Mindterm's settings by Amazon
- In that case, use a native SSH client such as the excellent [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

  - The [*AWS-SSH*](https://github.com/poma/AwsSsh) wrapper makes using PuTTY with multiple Amazon EC2 instances much more convenient. It can be downloaded as a single EXE file, no installation needed, [from here](https://github.com/poma/AwsSsh/downloads)

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Most clients copy each other's main functionality, you can try copy the text, go into the the the mindterm and do SHIFT + INSERT or copy the text and put the cursor where you want to paste and do a right click. [http://www.astro.umd.edu/resources/internal/ssh/MindTerm_User.pdf]

this worked for me for a lot of clients.

Comment: not justified vote down, actually read the documentation for mindterm.

Comment: I can't use this easily, and feel the downvote was justified. I did not downvote, hoewever.

Comment: okay maybe it is unclear? what do you mean by can't use this easily?

Comment: It appears to be a bt unweidly and seems to have trouble with long blocks of text.